# Почему не работает метод со Stream?

Tags: java

Не пойму, почему не работает anyMatch?
Когда вводится лист с операторами, которых нет в списке operators, noneMatch отрабатывает корректно.
Но когда один из операторов присутствует, anyMatch почему-то не отрабатывает. И на экран выводится результат из noneMatch.
Что я делаю не так? Как исправить метод?

```
static void isOperCorrect(ArrayList<Character> operList) {
        ArrayList<Character> operators = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('+', '-', '*', '/'));

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            boolean noneMatch = operList.stream().noneMatch(c -> c.equals(operators));
            boolean anyMatch = operList.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.equals(operators));

            if (noneMatch) {
                System.out.println("оператора нет в листе");
            } else if(anyMatch) {
                System.out.println("есть какой-то из операторов");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: как вы думаете, символ может быть эквивалентен списку? Т.е. может ли `'+' == ('+', '-')` ???

Comment: понятно, спасибо. А можете подсказать, как сделать, чтобы с помощью метода стрима пробежаться по списку операторов и узнать, есть ли соответствие?

Comment: `operators.contain(c)` но это по памяти. Правильное название метода подскажет подсказка в IDE, в которой вы код пишите

Comment: *Простите, за комментарий*, но вот `boolean anyMatch = operList.stream().anyMatch(c -> operators.stream().anyMatch(d -> c.equals(d)));`

Comment: спасибо! при изучении работы со стримами мне любая помощь полезна!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете сделать так, то есть пройтись по каждому элементу operList и проверить есть он в operators или нет

```
operList.forEach(c -> {
        if (operators.contains(c)) {
            System.out.println("something");
        } else {
            System.out.println("something other");
        }
});
```

Или же использовать noneMatch, anyMatch

```
boolean noneMatch = operList.stream().noneMatch(operators::contains);
boolean anyMatch = operList.stream().anyMatch(operators::contains);
```

Comment: спасибо большое! сейчас попробую!